# After dart update, Intellij IDEA still with past version

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I had Dart 2.1 v, then i update with

```
 brew upgrade dart
```

After that i can check dart version:

```
 brew info dart
```

Everything its fine, now is 2.7 v. But when i want to create a new project on IntelliJ IDEA still with 2.1v, i know i need to change, but on preference options "languages & Frameworks" Dart is not there.

[image]

Comment: Check that Dart plugin is installed and enabled.

Comment: Plugin is ok, and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to/can not change the Dart version for new projects in IntelliJ settings. Just be sure to use the correct Dart SDK path (e.g. the SDK that you have updated to 2.7) when creating a new project.

In `pubspec.yaml` you can see that the Dart version is >= 2.0.0 && < 3.0.0, so the project always uses the Dart version of the specified SDK. Thus your projects will always use the latest version of Dart 2.x. All minor updates within version 2.x are backward compatible, so there is no problem to always use the latest version.